# when consume message from kafka,usually with a group id.But,SimpleConsumer just use a clientName.The clientName is group id?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

when consume message from kafka,usually with a group id.But,SimpleConsumer API just use a clientName.The clientName is group id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of SimpleConsumer, clientName is just an identifier for the client. It is not group id. In fact there is no concept of consumer groups in SimpleConsumer.

Please refer to [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/0.8.0+SimpleConsumer+Example) - *The main reason to use a SimpleConsumer implementation is you want greater control over partition consumption than Consumer Groups give you.*

[High Level Consumer](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Group+Example) has the concept of consumer groups.

*The ‘group.id’ string defines the Consumer Group this process is consuming on behalf of.*

**Consumer Group** is a high level concept in which a particular message is consumed by only one of the consumers which belong to the same group